# I can not duplicate an angular component with a Syncfusion Pie Chart, it breaks

Tags: angular, charts, syncfusion

I created a custom angular component with a Syncfusion chart (Accumulation Pie Chart). When I render just one component everything is OK, but when I try two or more of the same component, it always breaks.

I'm using Angular 7 and SYNCFUSION EJ2. 
I'm sharing a Stackblitz link of my code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qyitdv?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Thanks for any help,

Rodrigo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `id="container"` in `custom.component.html`.
An id has to be unique in HTML. This is not the case when you have multiple charts.

Comment: I though I changed that before, but yes, you are right. I just made a class="container" and its works. Thanks, it really helps. Best regards.